# Is it possible to convert this expression into a NAND GATE Circuit?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am trying to construct a logic circuit for the expression (NOT Q & P) OR R - using only NAND gates.

I have tried this, can someone confirm if what I have done is correct? if not what do i need to change?

Corrected Version:
I am unsure on how to carry on from here - can somebody help?
[image]

Comment: Most obviously, you said the assignment was to design a circuit using only NAND gates, but you seem to have a NOT and an OR gate in your circuit.

Comment: @MJD - I have tried to correct it but i am getting confused on adding the OR R bit to the circuit - is the bit i have done now correct?

Answer (score 1):

In your above circuit you have a NOT gate and an OR gate. The main thing you need to do is convert these gates to NAND form.

Presumably you know NOT P $\equiv$ P NAND P. This can be checked via a truth table quite easily and is also fairly intuitive.

Hence P AND Q $\equiv$ NOT (P NAND Q) $\equiv$ (P NAND Q) NAND (P NAND Q).

Also P OR Q $\equiv$ (P NAND P) NAND (Q NAND Q).

From there you just have to translate this into a circuit diagram and remove any unnecessary double negatives.

Comment: I have added my corrected version but i am getting stuck on how to add the OR R bit to the circuit